# Problems with passing arguments to php scripts called from within sh scripts

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have the following .sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
php -f /test_folder/test.php dosomething
echo "test string"
```

`var_dump($_SERVER['argv'])` inside test.php returns this:

```
array(2) {
 [0]=>
  string(31) "/test_folder/test.php"
 [1]=>
  " string(12) "dosomething
}
```

which is problematic because of `" string(12) "dosomething` part. The quotes are incorrect and the argument gets parsed incorrectly by the script.

When I remove `echo "test string"` from the sh file and run it again I correctly get `string(11) "dosomething"`. The issue seems to be the newline after php line. 
I'm using Notepad++ on Windows, encoding is UTF8 - can any of these be a problem?

How to go to the new line without breaking the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem are **Windows-style `\r\n` (CRLF) line endings in your `bash` script** - possibly just *one*, namely on the line that contains the `php` call.<sup>[1]</sup>

I suspect that when you added line `echo "test string"` to the script later, you used a different editor (or differently configured editor) than the one the script was originally created with.

Verify the presence of Windows line endings with `cat -et script.sh`: if you see `^M$` in the output, you do have them.

To fix this problem:

- Convert your `*.sh` script to Unix `\n`-only line endings, and try again; you have several options:

  - Use utility `dos2unix`, if you have it installed (it is available through the package managers of many platforms).
  - Use a standard utility such as `awk`; e.g.:
    `awk '{ sub("\r$", ""); print } script.sh > script-fixed.sh`
  - See if Notepad++ can convert an existing file to Unix line endings.

    - **Update**: @Alan (the OP) reports that line endings can be set/converted via the `Edit > EOL Conversion` menu item.
- In the future, make sure that your editor uses Unix-style line endings when you edit Unix shell scripts.

---

<sup>[1] If *all* lines had Windows line endings, the shebang line wouldn't work, and invocation of your script - assuming it is marked as executable and invoked *directly* - would fail fundamentally with `/bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`</sup>

Comment: thanks! Line endings were ^M$ for all ines except the last one which is why the script worked when the php line was last. I used dos2unix to fix the problem but in Notepad++ line endings can be set/converted too in `Edit > EOL Conversion` menu.

Comment: @Alan: Thanks for the feedback; I've added your Notepad++ tip to the answer.